# Start an Android activity from an HTML link in a webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview

In an Android activity I am displaying a webview.

```
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/cloud.html");
```

The webview loads a local HTML file that builds a cloud of keywords with a javascript file. (source: http://www.goat1000.com/tagcanvas.php)

```
<script src="tagcanvas.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function() {
    try {
      TagCanvas.Start('myCanvas','tags',{depth: 0.8, maxSpeed: 0.03});
    } catch(e) {
      // something went wrong, hide the canvas container
      document.getElementById('myCanvasContainer').style.display = 'none';
    }
```

The keywords are generated from a list of HTML links defined in the HTML file

```
<div id="tags">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/location1">keyword1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/location2">keyword2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/location3">keyword3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

When a user taps on a link, instead of staying in the webview and going to the corresponding location, I would like him to start a new Android activity, so obviously with Android code

I have found resources showing an example of how to make Android and Javascript "communicate" with an interface but I didn't manage to make it work in my case.

Edit:
My implementation thanks to the answer of Vlad

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) { 
            Intent intent = new Intent(Act1.this, Act2.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); //ugly solution to avoid starting 2 activities, not ideal but it works              
            startActivity(intent);
            return true; //I always return true because I never want to open an HTML link
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a custom `WebViewClient` to the `WebView`, and intersect `url` loading in it:

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {


    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
       // check the URL, and do whatever you need to do according to the URL


       // return true; // if you handled URL, and WebView should not load it
          return false; // for the WebView to load the URL
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Vlad, it works like a charm. I didn't know such method existed.

Comment: Hey Vlad, the code I've put inside the method shouldOverrideUrlLoading is executed twice. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @Don might be cause of some redirects, or another reason. Show how you added a client, and I might see why it does.

Comment: I have edited my initial question with my implementation, please read last edit at the bottom

Comment: @Don, I unfortunately can't see a reason why it is called twice so far...

Comment: no problem, it has probably something to do with the javascript, not your solution. Thanks for your help again